# jquery.offset() is not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery scroll function to check if an element has entered the visible area of browser. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
.gg{display: none; background: green}
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  <div class="gg">asjacnsn</div><br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>

  asjacnsn<br/>
  asjacnsn<br/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(window).trigger("scroll");
$(window).scroll(function(){
//alert("dg");
if(($(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()) > $(".gg").offset().top){
alert("gg is visible");
$(".gg").fadeIn(2000)
}
})
})

  </script>
  </body>


  </html>
```

The problem is that the alert "gg is visible" comes when I start scrolling on page load. I debugged the offset position of `.gg` div by doing this:

```
$(".gg").offset().top
```

and it came out to be `0`. The next time I scroll, I get the right offset position of `$(".gg").offset().top` to be `=1108`. What am I doing wrong, that on first scroll the offset of `.gg` is coming wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `($(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: you can normally test for `$(window).scrollTop() > $(".gg").offset().top`

Comment: it come to be 637 on my system, my issue is actually that the alert should NOT come when i just start to scroll (bacuse at that time the gg div is not visible), the second time the alert is coming fine

Comment: you can use a pretty condition here, if `$(window).scrollTop()` = 0 then set the value of `$(window).height()`.

Comment: fixed it: in css i wrote:  .gg{ display: none} doue to whichj on page load the first time its position was not clear to browser as it was not blocked. so i did thos: .gg(visibility: hidden) and it worked.

Comment: great job, now go ahead.